# exclude a post from wp_query loop wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I show my last post in a page with this code:

```
$query1 = new WP_Query();
$query1->the_post();
```

and it further with:

```
$id = $query->ID;
```

to retrive last post ID
so I wrote a new wp_query and I want to exclue that ID from the results:
I wrote this but it don't work:

```
$query2-> new WP_Query('p=-$id');
```

what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't excluded anything. [Read the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters). `p=` **includes** posts. It does not exclude them. What you need is `post__not_in`

```
$query2-> new WP_Query(array('post__not_in' = array($id)));
```

Answer (score 1):

My code is works fine:

```
$ID =array('1,2,3,4,5');
$news = new WP_Query(array('
    'post_type'    => 'post',
    'showposts'    =>3,
    'order'        => 'DESC',
    'post__not_in' => $ID
));
if ( $news->have_posts() ) :
    echo '<div>';
        while ( $news->have_posts() ) : $news->the_post(); ?>`

            //Your code here
```